# GGplot2 facet_wrap() histograms given a value of other column

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a large dataframe `data` that looks like this

```
     state    values
1      0       0.25
2      1       0.73
3      1       0.21
4      2       0.95
5      3       0.37
6      0       0.72
7      2       0.81
8      1       0.13
9      1       0.05
10     3       0.46
```

I would like to use `facet_wrap()` to create four histograms: each one of them would correspond to values for a given value of `state`, so i.e. `value` histogram only for the observations that come from the `state == 1.`  At the same time I want my histograms to have the same x values: `min` and `max` of the whole dataset, so that I can compare them easily. The number of observations for each class may vary.

I tried to do that in this fashion, but it's obviously wrong.

```
ggplot(gather(data), aes(value)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 6) + 
  facet_wrap(~ values + state, scales = "free_x")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
df %>% 
  mutate(state=factor(state)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=values)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 6)+
  facet_wrap(.~state)
```

[image]